# Child window drawing issue in win32

Tags: winapi, win32gui

To  Start with , this is the desired look that I want to achieve but with rounded corners of the white region, and am not fully successful in doing so
[image: desired look but with rounded corner of white region]

To achieve this , I have identified the screen co-ordinates of the rectangle which is to be made white and created a static text window and set a rounded region using this:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    SetRect( &Rect,... );
                hSubWnd = CreateWindow("STATIC",NULL,SS_LEFT|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,Rect.left,Rect.top,(Rect.right-Rect.left),(Rect.bottom-Rect.top),hFrame,(HMENU)NULL,NULL,NULL);


                hrgn = CreateRoundRectRgn(Rect.left, Rect.top, Rect.right, Rect.bottom,15,15);
                SetWindowRgn(hSubWnd,hrgn,TRUE);
```

Then to color the region sett above I used the following:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
            //SetBkColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(0,0,0));
            if((HWND)lParam == hSubWnd)
            {
                SetBkMode((HDC)wParam,TRANSPARENT);

                return (INT_PTR )CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
            }
            break;
```

This makes the region colored white but the white region is not rounded as I expected.
Here are my questions:

1- How to make SetWindowRgn() work for child controls ?Is my approach correct or I need to take some other way to achieve my goal(rounding off the corners of the child)?

2- The parent window has WS_CLIPCHILDREN style enabled , which means that whatever I do in WM_PAINT of the main windows is not going to paint the child window area. I need some text to be put in the white region of the child window as well. Where do I do that ? TextOut() doesnt seem to work inside WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC  handler.

Should I change the window class of the child from "STATIC" to some custom class and write the WindowProc() for the child, wherein I handle the WM_PAINT  to draw text on it?

Kindly provide your suggestions.

Comment: is variable `hrgn` global? does the call to `SetWindowRgn()` return a nonzero value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say that you're handling `WM_PAINT` for your main window anyway to draw text, I recommend skipping the complexity of child controls and regions altogether.

I mean, all you want is a white rounded rectangle on your window's background? So draw it yourself. This is trivially accomplished using the [`RoundRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162944.aspx) function.

If you need the static control to determine the coordinates of the RoundRect (this can make things a lot easier when dealing with, e.g., different DPI settings), you can leave it there but make it invisible.

Sample code:

```
void OnPaint(HWND hWnd)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    // Create and select a white brush.
    HBRUSH hbrWhite = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    HBRUSH hbrOrig = SelectObject(ps.hdc, hbrWhite);

    // Create and select a white pen (or a null pen).
    HPEN hpenWhite = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    HPEN hpenOrig = SelectObject(ps.hdc, hpenWhite);

    // Optionally, determine the coordinates of the invisible static control
    // relative to its parent (this window) so we know where to draw.
    // This is accomplished by calling GetClientRect to retrieve the coordinates
    // and then using MapWindowPoints to transform those coordinates.

    // Draw the RoundRect.
    RoundRect(ps.hdc, Rect.left, Rect.top, Rect.right, Rect.bottom, 15, 15);

    // If you want to draw some text on the RoundRect, this is where you do it.
    SetBkMode(ps.hdc, TRANSPARENT);
    SetTextColor(ps.hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0)); // red text
    DrawText(ps.hdc, TEXT("Sample Text"), -1, &Rect, DT_CENTER);

    // Clean up after ourselves.
    SelectObject(ps.hdc, hbrOrig);
    SelectObject(ps.hdc, hpenOrig);
    DeleteObject(hbrWhite);
    DeleteObject(hpenWhite);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}
```

Comment: That really sounds good. Thanks a lot , will try it and let you know .:) There is a sea of API's to know about ..lol...:P

Comment: Did not run this code yet, but just trying to understand. You made a white brush and a white pen and then used it to draw the RoundRect(). How does that set the background of the rounded rect? DOes the api take care of that ? As you can see in the image i want a background which has a white rounded rect on top of a blue window background.

Comment: Okay I went through the documentation of RoundRect() and got the answer.

Comment: The parent window already has a background of light blue (I'm assuming). All RoundRect does is draw a white round rectangle on top of the existing background.